# Switch the values in quoted string to run function

Tags: r

I am been struggling with an issue which seems to have simple solution if my brain work well. I have to run a SQL stored procedure in SQL server database on monthly basis by changing the value of from_date and to_date. I could not figure out how I change the value in a quoted string. Here is my code using paste() which gives me error.

```
to_date <- '20160229'
from_date <- '20160201'
require(RODBC)
dWA_ABCD_BT_D <-  odbcDriverConnect('driver={SQL Server}; server=ABCD;        database=dWA_ABCD_BT_D; trusted_connection=true')
sens.raw <- sqlQuery( dWA_ABCD_BT_D,   "exec m_rawData_sens @from_dt = '20140301' , @to_dt = '20160229'  "  )
# Here the code using paste() that never worked-------------
sens.raw <- sqlQuery( dWA_ABCD_BT_D, paste("exec", "m_rawData_sens","@from_dt =", sQuote(from_date) , ",", "@to_dt =",  sQuote(to_date) , sep="  "  ))
# also tried without sQuote()
sens.raw <- sqlQuery( dWA_ABCD_BT_D, paste("exec", "m_rawData_sens","@from_dt =", from_date , ",", "@to_dt =",  to_date , sep="  "  ))
odbcClose(dWA_ABCD_BT_D)
```

Here is my error message

```
[1] "42000 102 [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '‘'."                           
[2] "[RODBC] ERROR: Could not SQLExecDirect 'exec  m_rawData_sens  @from_dt =  ‘20160201’  ,  @to_dt =  ‘20160229’'"
```

I have to change the from_date and to_date every month for 16 of those SP execution from R. any help is much appreciated from R community....thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From `?sQuote()` to use ASCII `0x27` single quote, you may have to put this line before the `paste()`:

```
options( useFancyQuotes=FALSE)
```

another workaround would be to put the single quote directly in your strings, but use `paste0()` to avoid spaces between quote and value:

```
paste0("exec ", "m_rawData_sens ","@from_dt='", from_date , "', ", "@to_dt ='",  to_date, "'"  )
```

Comment: need a space in between, "exec" and SP. it worked thank you    paste0("exec ","  ", "m_rawData_sens ","  ", " @from_dt ='", from_date , "', ", "@to_dt ='",  to_date, "'")